# I'm stuck outside the map and I can't get out!

Tags: zelda-link-to-the-past

I was playing Legend of Zelda: Link to the Past and I had a kind of no-clip cheat enabled. I was walking around the village in the dark world when I decided to clip through some trees to get to the next screen. However I didn't realize that I was at the edge of the map and there was no next screen. So when I clipped through, Link started an endless screen-transitioning loop moving south. Here is a screenie of my problem: [image]

Just imagine the screen and Link forever moving south (or down).
Is there a way I can kill myself and spawn at link's house? (I have three fairies : /)

Comment: Also, Because the screen is transitoning in an endless loop, I can't acsess my inventory or use any tools/weapons.

Comment: I don't think so, it seems they're caught in a game-breaking infinite loop. The only way to fix is to reset (that I'm aware of). Guess cheaters really do never prosper haha (no ill-will intended, just a funny comment)

Comment: maybe I could use a possition editor?

Comment: Possibly, I'm not to familiar with the world of mods and cheats, never really been for me :S erm.. spose what harm could be in trying if you're stuck already

Comment: @treyBake If I reset, I will only lose one dungon and two heart containers. It would take ~1 hour of catching up. thanks for ur help :)

Comment: Yeah that's not as bad as it could be, I thought that would be the case based on the screeny, must be near those annoying rock throwing mofos.

Comment: posted as an answer :)

Comment: This is a higher resolution than I remember...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no way to fix this in-game. With the possibility of other mods that allow placement of Link onto the grid might fix it, but I'm not familiar with such mods.

The issue is that you've caused an infinite loop, in dev terms, this is the worst-case scenario. It's game-breaking as it can't be exited without forcing the loop to exit. Unfortunately for you, the action triggering the loop can't be cancelled as it reached the end of the axis with movement still being triggered.

The only way to fix is to reset the game and catch up to where you were, just don't go off the map this time ;)